# Jquery Html Form Ajax With Spring 405 Method Not allowed

Tags: html, jquery, spring-mvc

I have deployed my Spring project in Tomcat and startr the tomcat. I wrote one html page to call the `spring MVC using ajax`.

It says  405 Method Not Allowed.

I am wondering if i run the same url in browser it is working. Please any one can help me?
I have my html page in another folder

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/SampleWebService/sample/sample-user",
        cache: false,               
        data:'firstName=' + $("#firstName").val() + "&lastName=" + $("#lastName").val() + "&currentCompany=" + $("#currentCompany").val(),
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cross-domain problem. Set

> crossDomain: 'TRUE'

The default value is FALSE for security reasons.